# Android App - New Release on Play Store using same Keystore for a Safe Update

Tags: android, keystore, fingerprint

I'm working on a new Version of an existing Android App, published on Play Store.
I've realized a new next version. During the creation of new release, Play Store requires the upload of Bundle APK/AAB File.
The file requires to be signed with a key which has a specific SHA-1, named "UPLOAD_FINGERPRINT".

Now, I've a file .iks that include a KeyAlias, who have the fingerprint "UPLOAD_FINGERPRINT". After I've generated the Signed Bundle/APK with Android Studio using this Key, does the App will be updated on devices without lost data of users?

Comment: Only original keystore can be used. You cannot use another keystore even if Alias and passwords are the same....the FILE should be EXACTLY the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to use a different Keystore, and Play Store says me the fingerprint was different respect the certificate was expected. Now I've used the right Keystore, and the upload goes fine without error.
So, does I have used the right Keystore (the password is the same in this project)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.